# JOIN operator in SQL query is not returning intended result

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to use `JOIN` operator to bring result here is my code:

```
create table emp(E_id integer, e_name varchar(100), d_ID integer , primary key(e_id));
create table dep (d_ID integer, d_name varchar(100), manager_id integer ,primary key(d_ID) , FOREIGN KEY (manager_id) REFERENCES emp(E_id));
alter table emp add FOREIGN KEY(d_ID) references dep(d_ID);

insert  into dep values(11,'computer',1);
insert  into dep values(12,'commerce',2);
insert  into dep values(13,'technology',3);

insert into emp values(1,'vishal',11) ;
insert into emp values(2,'sachin',12) ;
insert into emp values(3,'deepal',13) ;
insert into emp values(4,'sumit',11) ;
insert into emp values(5,'vinay',11) ;
insert into emp values(6,'ravish',14) ;
```

I want to search manager of a particular employee with join operators like manager of vinay result should be vishal
 I used the nested query:

```
  select e_name 
from emp 
where e_id in (select  manager_id
               from dep 
               where dep.d_id in(select d_ID 
                                       from emp 
                                       where emp.e_name ='sumit'));
```

I am getting the right result, but when I use `JOIN` operator it not working it show me result

```
vishal
sachin
deepal
```

i expcet result vishal here is code:

```
select e_name 
from emp natural join dep 
where dep.manager_id=emp.e_id and emp.e_name='sumit';
```

Comment: Whats the expected result?

Comment: i expecte like nested query result

Comment: natural join simply joins the same columns names between both tables in this case  `d_ID` so `select e_name from emp natural join dep where dep.manager_id=emp.e_id;` should be the same as `select e_name from emp inner join dep on emp.d_ID = emp.d_ID.where dep.manager_id=emp.e_id;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Comment: it depends on db & settings, but maybe the subtle difference between `d_id` and `d_ID` (case sensitivity) breaks the "natural join" (coz' this bases on column name)?? ...and then still the where clause is confusing/redundant

Comment: Your sample data are wrong. None of `d_ID` in table `emp` match the referenced column `d_ID` in table `dep`.

Comment: @forpas is any problem with alter table emp add FOREIGN KEY(d_ID) references dep(d_ID);

Comment: @Vishalchoudhary The values 11, 12, 13, 14 of the column `d_ID` of table `emp` must reference the column `d_ID` of table `dep` whic are 1, 2, 3 but they don't since they don't match.

Comment: @forpas correct i should change them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join `emp` to `dep` and back to `emp` again:

```
select e.e_name 
from emp join dep 
on dep.d_id = emp.d_id
inner join emp e
on e.e_id = dep.manager_id
where emp.e_name='sumit';
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6fh3LK7DLQc8SSR34YhXNE/0)

Comment: can you please exaplain what use of inner join in this code its show right reslut with out using inner (with join only )

Comment: @Vishalchoudhary join and inner join are the same thing. I tend to use inner join when I write code, but now you made me that in the above code I used once join and once inner join. Anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `natural join`!  It chooses the `join` conditions.  You just want an `inner join`:

```
select e.e_name
from emp e inner join
     dep d
     on d.manager_id = e.e_id;
```